# sharepoint 2013 list permissions for SPservices + query

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

I have used SPservices to write to a Sharepoint 2010 list in the past with no problem and I just migrated to Sharepoint 2013, but it is not writing to the list. Is there anything option I need to turn on OR enable to allow "writing" to the list to occur. Does the list need to become an app?

Comment: Could you post the script? Unlikely to see any help otherwise.

Comment: I solved this issue by not using the  imported list from excel, but but by downloading it as a template- then uploading to sharepoint as an app list template

Comment: Great! Glad you got it nailed!